# Handling entity framework relations in json.net

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have an ASP MVC Web Api project that outputs json using json.net. I have for example the following models:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int TypeModelId {get;set;}
    public virtual TypeModel TypeModel {get;set;}
}

public class TypeModel
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<ModelA> ModelAs {get;set;}
}
```

When I serialize a `ModelA` the output will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "test",
    "TypeModel": {
      "Name": "testtype1"
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible using json.net to have an output like this..

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "test",
    "TypeModel": "testtype1"
  }
]
```

..or do I have to copy the contents of `ModelA` to a new class which stores the `TypeModel` relation as string instead of reference? Maybe there are better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say the only way to do this is with a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). This is because, as you indicated, the type of TypeModel is a class `TypeModel` and not a string. If you are using Linq you could also just use an anonymous type in the following way.

```
return db.ModelAs.Single(x=>x.Id == id).Select(x=> new{
    x.Id,
    x.Name,
    TypeModel = x.TypeModel.Name
});
```

Comment: Too bad a DTO is the only way, but your Linq solution is better than creating additional classes. Another solution I found is to json-ignore the `TypeModel` class, and creating a `NotMapped` get property for `TypeModel.Name`, but unfortunately that will get the datamodel classes a bit messy.

Comment: Yes I have recently had the same issue with Annotating my classes when trying to serialise object with Web Api, I've found using DTOs to be the best way (better than anonymous types) as you get better consistency. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not true, json.net can handle loop reference handling, dto is an old method, still good, but you can enable in the serializer the option to handle loopreferences as long as it is mvc5 and maybe also mvc4.
More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23044770/1345207