# MVC serialize json using Json.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have this code inside a Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var tickets = db.Tickets.Include(t => t.AreaOfBusiness).Include(t => t.Assignee).Include(t => t.Severity).Include(t => t.TicketStatu);
    return this.Json(tickets.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

but I get

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Ticket_2B104FE45830306408DA130C08090F61ADA6B8A0106592FECE85087B94B

when launching KendoGrid.

I read that NewtonSoft Json.Net can handle Circular Reference. I cannot understand how to use it.

Can you help me modify the code in order to use the Json.Net?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: what return `ToDataSourceResult`?

Comment: I want the equivelant code using NewtonSoft's Json.NET so that I wont have to drop Primary and Foreign Keys in my schema in order to avoid "Circular Reference"

Comment: Could you put the NewtonSoft Json.Net to understand this?

Comment: I have no idea! I want to substitute this >this.Json(tickets.ToDataSourceResult(request)) with NewtonSoft's tool. I do not know how, that's why I am posting the question :)

Answer (score 1):

`ToDataSourceResult` return the object `DataSourceResult`.

Kendo Documentation

**A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type**

The reason for this error is that the JavaScriptSerializer class used by the Json method cannot serialize object graphs which contain circular references (refer to each other). The best solution is to use View Model objects and avoid the serializing the properties which create the circular reference. Check the ["How do I avoid circular reference exceptions"](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-avoid-circular-reference-exceptions?) FAQ section for further information.

[see documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting#a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type)

**"How do I avoid circular reference exceptions?"**:

The JavaScriptSerializer class will throw an exception if the serialized object contains circular references. To avoid that use a View Model and exclude the properties which create the circular references

[see example](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-avoid-circular-reference-exceptions?)

[More data](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/todatasourceresult.aspx)

Comment: Thanx for your answer and links Andrea but I find it akward to have to cripple a very sane database schema in order to have a certain serializer work properly. Newtonsoft can handle circular reference so I prefer to give it a chance than ommiting columns and relations.

Comment: Thanx again! I may be boring but I cannot accept that EF entities that are produced by a relational database schema with PKs and FKs cannot be Json-ed!!! I want the ajax approach to the KendoUIGrid and I read that Json is a must. For testing purposes I left 5 tables, 1 "main" and 4 that feed the FKs of the first. Guess what? I got the same circular reference error! I am really getting dissapointed :(

Answer (score 1):

Or... you can enable json.net feature to serialize handling circular references for objects

in your *global.asax.cs*

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonMediaTypeFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.OfType<System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
jsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
jsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

remember to disable lazy loading or it will download the whole database, use include on dbsets to keep the relationships you want
and to parse the json that will behave like a dictionary now, example here: https://gist.github.com/keesey/7995398